# Sign of Potential Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential, conventions

[image]

The mass is released at height $h$ above the spring, how far will the spring move?
$E_i=mgh, E_f= kx^2/2+mgx$...why the second equation isn't $ E_f= kx^2/2-mgx$? Since it is below the "zero".

Comment: Indeed, the gravitational potential energy should be $-gmx$ (if $x$ is the distance that the spring is stretched downwards).

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of how you define your variable. Regardless of how you define your coordinate system the result shouldn't change. Consider 2 cases, the first one being how you currently defined your vertical axis, and the second one being with an origin at the foot of the spring. Let $\Delta x$ be a positive value which is the displacement of the spring.

**1st case**

$E_i=mgh$, $E_f=\frac{k\Delta x^2}{2}-mg\Delta x$ (minus because now the mass is on the other side of the origin) which yields from the conservation of the energy to $mgh=\frac{k\Delta x^2}{2}-mg\Delta x$.

**2nd case**

$E_i=mg(L_0+h)$ where $L_0$ is the length of the spring at rest. 
$E_f=\frac{k\Delta x^2}{2}+mg(L_0-\Delta x)$; which from the conservation of the energy yields to $mgh=\frac{k\Delta x^2}{2}-mg\Delta x$ since the $mgL_0$ cancel out.

My guess is that x has been defined algebrically, that is with a sign, and for this particular coordinate system its value is negative (i.e. $+mgx=-mg\Delta x$). The description was ambiguous as to whether $x$ had a sign or not ("how far" should be positive), I give you that.

Answer (score 1):

your coordinates are pointing up, let's call the coordinates y-axis.

at the top your initial coordinate is $y_i=h$, where $h$ is simply a distance, it's positive.

at the bottom your location is $y_f=-x$, where $x$ is again a positive value, indicating how far the spring will go down.

so, the equations comes up as $mgy_i=mgy_f+kx^2/2$, which is the same as $mgh=-mgx+kx^2/2$ or $mg(h+x)=kx^2/2$. The last equation is even more clear: the total travel distance is clearly $h+x$, that's how much potential energy changes, which must be equal to the kinetik energy gained.